# Reading a file into an array of strings C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, c-strings

I am having trouble reading a file into an array of strings in C. Here is my code:

```
  char mylittleBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];     //BUFFER_SIZE is 4096
  char *a;
  char **c;

  fprintf(stderr, "LOL\n");
  for(int i = 0; (a = fgets(mylittleBuffer, sizeof(mylittleBuffer), myInput)) != NULL; i++)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "a: %s\n", a);
      c[i] = malloc(sizeof(a));
      if (c[i] == NULL)
        printf("c[i] is NULL");
      c[i] = strdup(a);
      //      fprintf(stderr, "mylittleBuffer: %s\n", mylittleBuffer);                                                                                                                                                   
      fprintf(stderr, "c[i] %s\n", c[i]);
    }
```

It appears that only one line of the file is read as the program will print out `a` once. What happened to the other lines? I get no error messages...

1. What is the issue here?
2. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: sorry, I just edited. Is what I wrote sufficient?

Comment: You are reading a file, not writing a file. You have not initialized `c` to point to anything (you need to allocate space for it), so when you use `c[i]`, you are using undefined memory locations, invoking undefined behaviour. It is a miracle that it does not crash.  You will need to allocate space for the array of character pointers.

Comment: aha! Thanks! I changed `char **c` to `char *c[NUM_LINES]` so I guess I'll have to count the number of lines in the file. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: See my answer :D  Your variable `i` is already counting lines.  I like that you use 4096 for BUFFER_SIZE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialized `c` to point to anything (you need to allocate space for it), so when you use `c[i]`, you are using undefined memory locations, invoking undefined behaviour. It is a miracle that it does not crash. You will need to allocate space for the array of character pointers.

```
enum { INITIAL_SIZE = 2 };            // Set to a larger number when not debugging
char mylittleBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];     //BUFFER_SIZE is 4096
char *a;
size_t c_size = INITIAL_SIZE;
char **c = malloc(c_size * sizeof(*c));

if (c == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory (for c)\n");
    return;
}

fprintf(stderr, "LOL\n");
for (int i = 0; (a = fgets(mylittleBuffer, sizeof(mylittleBuffer), myInput)) != NULL; i++)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "a: %s\n", a);
    if (i >= c_size)
    {
         // Reallocate c to get more space
         size_t new_size = c_size * 2;
         void *new_space = realloc(c, new_size * sizeof(*c));
         if (new_space == 0)
         {
             // Release the already allocated c[i]
             // Release c
             fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (for more c)\n");
             return;
         }
         c_size = new_size;
         c = new_space;
    }
    // c[i] = malloc(sizeof(a));  // Leak - you use strdup() too
    c[i] = strdup(a);
    if (c[i] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "c[i] is NULL\n");
        // Release the already allocated c[i] strings
        // Release c
        return;
    }
    //      fprintf(stderr, "mylittleBuffer: %s\n", mylittleBuffer);
    fprintf(stderr, "c[%d] <<%s>>\n", i, c[i]);  // <<>> show where the string ends
}
```

I've kept your code mostly. Were it mine, `a` would not exist, `mylittleBuffer` would be just `buffer`, and that's what I'd use in the body of the loop in place of `a`.  I'd probably use a longer name for `c`, though I usually use shorter names than other people do.

Note how the code using `realloc()` avoids losing the pointer to the previously allocated memory if the call fails.  If it assigned directly to `c`, you'd lose the only reference to the previous memory allocation — a possibly major leak.

Given that the clean-up code is needed twice, I'd write a function to do it:

```
static void release_memory(size_t num, char **strings)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
        free(strings[i]);
    free(strings);
}
```

It would be called as:

```
release_memory(i, c);
```